# No filters yield no results - (stackoverflow home page has no questions)

Tags: bug, filtering

This recently started happening: I go to some stackoverflow question, then go to the home page, and there are no questions there.

[image: No questions on the home page!]

Comment: This doesn't always happen - so far it has happened to me no more than a couple of times.

Comment: Also, it is curious that there are 0 questions but 424 of the questions have bounties.

Comment: As a side note, if you [search google using that image and `site:meta.stackoverflow.com`](https://goo.gl/RdA1z7), the first result is the question that this is marked a duplicate of.